# AWS Serverless Web App for a theme park Cloud 9 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, aws-codecommit, aws-cloud9

[image: image from tutorial]

[image: image of the cloud 9 where i got the error]

While trying to push the downloaded code to populate your recently created CodeCommit repository i got this error:fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/theme-park-frontend/': The requested URL returned error: 403

i have not tried anything.

Comment: You had some confidential information in your screenshots there - I've removed that and replaced the external links with inline images.

Answer (score 1):

If you "have not tried anything" yet to solve the issue, immediately going to Stackoverflow and asking others to solve the problem for you is maybe not the right thing to do ;) Best check [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for any future questions you post here.

Anyway, the error message in your screenshot indicates that the git credentials haven't been set up correctly yet. Did you follow the instructions from the workshop, specifically the `git config` commands outlined [here](https://www.eventbox.dev/published/lesson/innovator-island/1-deploy/2-frontend.html#2-clone-the-code-base)?